# Как в FFmpeg удлинить видео относительно длины второго видео?

Tags: ffmpeg

У меня есть 2 видео.
Мне нужно одно из них удлинить (укоротить) автоматически по длине другого видео..
Я не знаю как это возможно..
Я знаю как склеивать 2 видео но это не то..

Comment: Пишете скрипт из 2 команд, в котором сначала считывается длительность одного видео, а затем это значение подается как параметр для обработки другого видео.

Comment: @Neolot На JS делать это и встраивать в bat файл его?

Comment: на cmd или bash, на чем вы там работаете.